# Admin class not defined in django

Tags: python, django

i try add my model into admin.
but error run while i create class for model.admin
i don't know why my class read is not defined.

i using python 3.6 and Django 2.0

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post


# Register your models here.


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'publish', 'status')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'publish', 'author')
    search_fields = ('title', 'body')
    raw_id_fields = ('author')
    date_hierarchy = ('publish')
    ordering = ['status', 'publish']

    admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

here my debug error :

> "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3\bin\runnerw.exe"
>   C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   C:/Users/FIANUAENA/PycharmProjects/mysite/manage.py runserver 8000
>   Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x05E1EE88>
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
>   line 225, in wrapper
>           fn(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
>   line 113, in inner_run
>           autoreload.raise_last_exception()
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
>   line 248, in raise_last_exception
>           raise _exception[1]
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 327, in execute
>           autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
>   line 225, in wrapper
>           fn(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py",
>   line 24, in setup
>           apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
>   line 120, in populate
>           app_config.ready()
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py",
>   line 23, in ready
>           self.module.autodiscover()
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin__init__.py",
>   line 26, in autodiscover
>           autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py",
>   line 47, in autodiscover_modules
>           import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\venv\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>         File "", line 994, in _gcd_import
>         File "", line 971, in _find_and_load
>         File "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>         File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>         File "", line 678, in exec_module
>         File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\blog\admin.py", line 8, in 
>           class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>         File "C:\Users\FIANUAENA\PycharmProjects\mysite\blog\admin.py", line 16, in PostAdmin
>           admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
>       NameError: name 'PostAdmin' is not defined

Thank's for help

Answer (score 5):

Unindent your admin call:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'publish', 'status')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'publish', 'author')
    search_fields = ('title', 'body')
    raw_id_fields = ('author')
    date_hierarchy = ('publish')
    ordering = ['status', 'publish']

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Answer (score -2):

thank's my problem has been fixed.
just change my code :

from :

```
from .models import Post
```

to :

```
from blog.models import *
```

Comment: Either of those imports should work. The issue was the indentation, as Stolson said.

Comment: Apart from this being the wrong answer, import * are not good practice